# Dynamic Calculation from formula in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Below are my tables and I want to calculation as per formula and insert in table3 with employees.

I have 3 tables

```
table1 payhead master 
table2 employee payheadwise salary
table3 (the destination table)
```

I want to calculate as per formula column and insert into table3

For example in table 2 employeid-E001 in Pay1-2000 so for Pay2 which is formula column should calculate as per pay1 value and insert into table 3 like empid-E001,payid-pay1,amount-2000 next,Empid-E001,Payid-pay2,amount-240(calculate as 2000*12/100) NextRow-Empid-E001,Payid-pay3,Amount-2240(pay1+pay2) .so as per formula it should be calculate and insert into 3rd table.
please, somebody, help me.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1  
(
     ID VARCHAR(5), 
     formula VARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE #table2  
(
     employeid VARCHAR(5), 
     payhead VARCHAR(5), 
     amount MONEY
)

CREATE TABLE #table3   
(
     employeid VARCHAR(5), 
     payiD VARCHAR(5), 
     amount MONEY
)

INSERT INTO #Table1 
VALUES ('PAY1', NULL), ('PAY2', '(PAY1+PAY2*12%)'), ('PAY3', 'PAY1 + PAY2')

INSERT INTO #Table2 
VALUES ('E001', 'PAY1', 2000), ('E002', 'PAY1', 5000), ('E003', 'PAY1', 3000)

INSERT INTO #Table2 
VALUES ('E001', 'PAY3', 1000), ('E002', 'PAY3', 3000), ('E003', 'PAY3', 2000)
```

Comment: someone please help..

Comment: You need to help yourself - you need to explain the problem more clearly. Its really unclear what you are trying to ask. I have edited your question a little but it's very difficult to understand what you are talking about

Comment: i have 3 table as above and for 1st table i have some master data like payhead name with formula which would be calculated.second table is Employee with PayHead Amound i.e each emloyee has some salary structure which define there and from that amount it should be calculated and insert another table like Employee-PayHead-Amount format.for example For E001 it should be E001-Pay1-2000,E001-Pay2-Pay1*12*(2000*12/100)-240,E001-Pay3-2240.

Comment: You just splatted a bunch of words again. Please post a simple example. Also.... please delete all the duplicates of this question.

Comment: I really try to understand your question, but I still dont... I see your three tables, but it's not clear how the data in those tables are connected together.. I dont understand how the values should come together in table3.. Make one example in your original question (not as comment). Use real numbers.. Also, is the last `insert into #table2` correct or should it be `#table3` ?

Comment: please check table2 and table1.in table2 there are amount of related payhead id and in table1 there are payhead master table and table3 which is our final table will insert data after calculation from query.for example Employee1 which is ID-E001 and at the time of calculation,first it take employee and amout from table2 and calculates like Emp-E001,PayId-Pay1-2000 next Emp_E001,Payid-Pay2-which is formula like Pay1*12%=240,Next Emp-E001-Payid-Pay3 which also formula value will -2240 like this.hope u understand